# can't select view tables after make a role on mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I made a role with the name app_reader and gave it to the specific user, below the command:

```
CREATE ROLE app_reader;
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON dbname.* TO 'app_reader';
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test@2022';
GRANT app_reader TO testuser;
SET DEFAULT ROLE app_reader FOR testuser;
```

After success login with testuser but the user is not able to check view tables.

How to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Hmm.. does the user have SELECT privilege on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS?

Comment: I'm not sure cause I'm a new dba, how to give those privilege? @Akina